# Signature size discrepancy for MPC in the Head signature

Tags: signature, multiparty-computation

I have been puzzled by the following for a long time. In the (very well know in the field) paper:
[Improved Non-Interactive Zero Knowledge with Applications
to Post-Quantum Signatures](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/3243734.3243805)
, the authors introduce the so-called cut and choose technique to produce zk proofs. In particular, they show how to prove that $y=f(x)$ where x is secret. So for example, one can prove $\operatorname{AES}_k(m)=c$ keeping $k$ secret.

They claim that for the parameters
$m=631,n=64,\tau=23$
you can achieve $128$-bits of security (actually you achieve more).
They also claim that for a function that can be expresed with $1000$ multiplication gates (addition gates are free) they produce a signature of size $37$KB.

The puzzling thing, is that when applying the formula they give (here $\vert x\vert$ is the size of the secret, usually $16$ bytes):
$$
\text{signature size}
=2\kappa
+3\kappa\tau\log\frac{m}{\tau}
+\tau(\kappa\log(n)+\vert x\vert+
2000
+2\kappa)
$$

You get $14.3$KB much less than they claim!
I have run this computation a hundred times. Since no-one would want to include larger signature sizes than what strictly necessary, what am I missing?

Comment: I find in the paper is for the "communication complexity" on the bottom right of page marked 530, and equivalent (after reordering as in the question) to$$2\kappa+3\,\kappa\,\tau\log\frac M\tau+\tau\,(\kappa\,\log n+2\vert C\vert+\vert w\vert+2\kappa)$$ which is quite different from the question's formula as it was [originally](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/103305/1), and not only in the naming of the variables and of the result. In particular there's a $\kappa$ term on the left of $\log n$. It does not account for the whole of the discrepancy, though.

Comment: @fgrieu Thanks for taking a look. You are right, I copied it wrong on the question, but I used the right formula on my calculations. (Here $w=128$ and $\vert C \vert=1000$). So the discrepancy is still a major issue.

Comment: I am very familiar with the paper, but don’t have the answer to that (even after pondering for a few minutes about it). At this stage, I doubt anyone will have the answer on top of their head unless they have the exact calculations in mind. I would suggest emailing the authors of the paper (and posting an answer to your own question here once they answer).

Comment: @GeoffroyCouteau Sorry for the extremenly late reply. I'll do that now!